# How to add a delay before ng-show display/shows an element

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

Having -

```
<div ng-show="show"></div>
<button ng-click="show = !show">SHOW</button>
```

How could I make it such that the displaying/showing affected by the `show` change would be with a 1 second delay before ?

Any css , Angular , ngAnimate answer would be acceptable .

Answer (score 1):

Don't have inline code. Use functions in this case.

Inject `$timeout` in your controller.

```
$scope.toggleDisplay = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.show = !$scope.show;
    }, 1000);
};
```

Your template will then look like:

```
<div data-ng-show="show"></div>
<button data-ng-click="toggleDisplay()">SHOW</button>
```